# Dagger: How to cut down on injects maintenance?

Tags: android, dagger

I'm building an Android app that is making extensive use of Dagger for dependency injection.

I've separated my app into multiple logical packages, and I tried to split things up into multiple modules that all get included in a "main" module, in order to separate concerns.

However, now I have a problem where I have to maintain the injects { ... } list for each module, and it is getting very tedious and error prone.

For instance

```
@Module(
        injects = {
                ThingA.class
        },
        complete = false,
        library = false
)
public class FeatureAModule {
    @Provides
    public FeatureA providesFeature(FeatureAImpl featureA){
        return featureA;
    }
}

@Module(
        injects = {
                ThingB.class,
                AnotherThingB.class
        },
        complete = false,
        library = false
)
public class FeatureBModule {
    @Provides
    public FeatureB providesFeature(FeatureBImpl feature){
        return feature;
    }
}

@Module(
        injects = {
        },
        complete = true,
        library = false,
        includes = { FeatureAModule.class, FeatureBModule.class }
)
public class ApplicationModule {

}
```

If I add an @Injects annotation in a class but forget to add it to my injects list, I'll get a runtime exception. If I have a class that uses features from 2 modules I'll typically add the injects to both Modules, but then if I forget one and then I go and remove it from one of the modules I have to make sure it's not used anywhere else or else I'll then have that runtime exception.

Basically, I am trying to figure out a foolproof way to never have that "no injects registered" when I try to inject something (ideally at the dagger-compiler level).

Answer (score 0):

i ran into the same issue...
my solution was to **group the components of my app into the features** they belong to

then i created a **separate module for each feature** which has all the classes which require injection in its **injects** list.

this way the entire thing became managable, yet the entire *injects* list should become obsolete